# Why are the speakers on my HTC One so quiet?

Tags: audio, volume-control, htc-one, volume

I just got a new [HTC One](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_one-5313.php), and while it is brilliant, the speaker volume is awful. Headphones sound really good, but even with the media volume all the way up, the speakers are too quiet. This means that I often miss navigation directions, etc.

Is there a hidden speaker volume? Ideally, I do not want to install a custom ROM or root my phone, but any suggestions would be useful.

Comment: At least related: [How can I boost the music volume higher than the max limit?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/30527/16575) / [How can I make my Samsung Galaxy Nexus volume go louder than what stock allows?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17319/16575) / [How can I increase the maximum speaker volume?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/19426/16575) / [How to increase speaker volume of HTC Evo 3D](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/21266/16575)

Comment: Thanks for the links, but I was looking for something that doesnt require a special app / rooting / pointless advice to use earphones. My old galaxy S had good speaker volume. In fact it was so loud i pretty much always had it on silent......

Comment: I'm afraid then you're out of luck. But not having that particular device, I of course cannot say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking if BoomSound is activated. It is supposed to improve the sound a lot.You are supposed to see a "b" icon on the top bar when it is activated.

Go to Settings > Sound > Volumes

When using speakers it is enabled by default and it doesn't allow you to disable it. What may happen, though, is that when you have earphones plugged it, you can disable it. If, perhaps you have it disabled, then you remove the earphones and the HTC doesn't detect that you removed the earphones, BoomSound can be disabled.

If that's the case, try inserting the earphone again and enabling BoomSound. Then remove the earphones and see if that works.

I have an HTC M8 and and M9. I have had similar issues before.

Answer (score 1):

If the other answers don't work, you can try installing ViPER4Android, it can boost audio as much as you'd like. (though it will require root unfortunately.)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to check with another identical phone(from a friend, or from the store) Your phone might a defect

Comment: Perhaps, if this wasn't 2.5 years after the issue.